# A number theory question?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, $r$ be a positive integer. I have the following statement.

If $x \equiv a^r \mod p$ and $x \equiv b^r \mod q$ then there is a solution $d$ for the congruence 
$$x \equiv d^r \mod pq.$$

> **QUESTION.** Is there any proof or reference for that?

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem. What congruences for $d$ would imply the result?

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Daniel Fisher's comment:  In fact, this is the [easy case of the Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_moduli).